# Jest error: "preset @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel not found"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs

I have default jest.config.js but when i want run unit test i get an error message:

**Validation Error:
Preset @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel not found.**

I am using vue 2 with composition api plugin and typescript.

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest/presets/typescript-and-babel'
}
```

example.spec.ts:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, {
      props: { msg }
    })
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg)
  })
})
```

Comment: Do you have [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest) installed locally in your project?

Comment: Yes i have it installed as dev dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this problem with update jest plugin from:
`@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.12.1"`
to:
`@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.0"`